# dlib load jpeg files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dlib

I am trying to implement a program using dlib library. I have already been able to use dlib's all other files except the ones related to jpeg and png.

```
#include "dlib\image_io.h"


#define DLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT


int main(){

    dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel> arr1;

    dlib::load_jpeg(arr1,"sailboat1234.jpeg");

}
```

I have included to my project the `source.cpp` file and the ones inside the `dlib/external`. Also i have included into c++ general the `dlib-18.11` folder which contains the `dlib` folder. 
Lastly, the project is running on Visual studio 2012.

EDIT:

When I run the program the error: `error C2027: use of undefined type 'dlib::compile_time_assert<value>'` . Any ideas?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Please check my edited part

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the define before the headers for it to have any effect:

```
#define DLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT
#include "dlib\image_io.h"
```

For reference see this header:

```
image_loader\jpeg_loader.h
```

Comment: thanks this saved my life. I'm using this in Android jni.