# how to load jpeg file using DLIB libarary?

Tags: c++, image, libjpeg, dlib

After attempting to run a example program downloaded from [Here](http://dlib.net/face_landmark_detection_ex.cpp.html), I understand for working with jpeg files , I must add  **#define DLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT** directive to the project. but before that It's necessary to download jpeg library and add it to the project. I did These steps:

1.Download **jpegsr9a**.zip from [here](http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsr9a.zip) and unzipped it.

2.Download **WIN32.mak** and paste it into the jpeg root folder

3.Open  Developer Command Prompt from visual studio 2013 tools

4.In command prompt type : **nmake -f makefile.vc setup-v10**

5.After these steps jpeg.sln created ,the note is when I open jpeg.sln in VS2013 the message come:

[image]

maybe base of the problem start from here , I don't know

6.Build the jpeg.sln with the proper configuration (I built it many times with different configurations, recently I built it using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YirxxtFpJIU) .)
at the end of building the error came :**"unable to start jpeg.lib"**
but in release folder or debug folder (depend on configuration) jpeg.lib was created

7. open main project which is using DLIB for detecting face,I added jpeg root folder to Additonal Include Directory and jepegroot/release to Additional Libarary Directories ,then change the UseLibrary dependencies to "yes" and I also added jpeg.lib to the dependecies.

during building the project errors come:
[image]

This is the source which I trying to build and run

```
//#define HAVE_BOOLEAN
#define DLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT
#include <dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h>
#include <dlib/image_processing/render_face_detections.h>
#include <dlib/image_processing.h>
#include<dlib/image_transforms.h>
#include <dlib/gui_widgets.h>
#include <dlib/image_io.h>
#include <iostream>
//
using namespace dlib;
using namespace std;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    try
    {
        // This example takes in a shape model file and then a list of images to
        // process.  We will take these filenames in as command line arguments.
        // Dlib comes with example images in the examples/faces folder so give
        // those as arguments to this program.
        if (argc == 1)
        {
            cout << "Call this program like this:" << endl;
            cout << "./face_landmark_detection_ex shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat faces/*.jpg" << endl;
            cout << "\nYou can get the shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat file from:\n";
            cout << "http://dlib.net/files/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2" << endl;
            return 0;
        }

        // We need a face detector.  We will use this to get bounding boxes for
        // each face in an image.
        frontal_face_detector detector = get_frontal_face_detector();
        // And we also need a shape_predictor.  This is the tool that will predict face
        // landmark positions given an image and face bounding box.  Here we are just
        // loading the model from the shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat file you gave
        // as a command line argument.
        shape_predictor sp;
         deserialize(argv[1])>>sp;


        image_window win, win_faces;
        // Loop over all the images provided on the command line.
        for (int i = 2; i < argc; ++i)
        {
            cout << "processing image " << argv[i] << endl;
            array2d<rgb_pixel> img;
            load_image(img, argv[i]);
            // Make the image larger so we can detect small faces.
            pyramid_up(img);

            // Now tell the face detector to give us a list of bounding boxes
            // around all the faces in the image.
            std::vector<rectangle> dets = detector(img);
            cout << "Number of faces detected: " << dets.size() << endl;

            // Now we will go ask the shape_predictor to tell us the pose of
            // each face we detected.
            std::vector<full_object_detection> shapes;
            for (unsigned long j = 0; j < dets.size(); ++j)
            {
                full_object_detection shape = sp(img, dets[j]);
                cout << "number of parts: " << shape.num_parts() << endl;
                cout << "pixel position of first part:  " << shape.part(0) << endl;
                cout << "pixel position of second part: " << shape.part(1) << endl;
                // You get the idea, you can get all the face part locations if
                // you want them.  Here we just store them in shapes so we can
                // put them on the screen.
                shapes.push_back(shape);
            }

            // Now let's view our face poses on the screen.
            win.clear_overlay();
            win.set_image(img);
            win.add_overlay(render_face_detections(shapes));

            // We can also extract copies of each face that are cropped, rotated upright,
            // and scaled to a standard size as shown here:
            dlib::array<array2d<rgb_pixel> > face_chips;
            extract_image_chips(img, get_face_chip_details(shapes), face_chips);
            win_faces.set_image(tile_images(face_chips));

            cout << "Hit enter to process the next image..." << endl;
            cin.get();
        }
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    {
        cout << "\nexception thrown!" << endl;
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I can choose other alternatives but I spend too much time to reach here , I want to know How I can solve this problem and load jpeg file when using DLIB

I also read these links:

[Compiling libjpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652178/compiling-libjpeg)

http://www.dahlsys.com/misc/compiling_ijg_libjpeg/index.html

[dlib load jpeg files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803399/dlib-load-jpeg-files)

http://sourceforge.net/p/dclib/discussion/442518/thread/8a0d42dc/

Comment: I think the problem refer to jpeg.lib

Comment: Have you made your project in older version of Visual studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by below instruction, please follow it.

**- Add include directory in VC++**
[image]

**- Include source.cpp**

[image]

**- Add add files in dlib/external/libjpeg to project**

[image]

**- Define in Preprocessor**

[image]

-- You don't need to use any additional library.

Comment: Why don't you use cmake to create your visual studio project as suggested by http://dlib.net/compile.html?

Comment: Actually I tried to do it but failed, so I had to config by manual as above.

Comment: Did you type the exact commands at the top of this page? http://dlib.net/compile.html.  I just did and they compile without error in visual studio 2013

Comment: sorry because my question refers to 3 months ago and I  did my project by another tool, It takes time to check your answer and then mark it. thank you