# how to load jpeg image in Visual studio 2015 with Dlib?

Tags: dlib

Sorry for the stupid question.

I red the answer on the official website http://dlib.net/compile.html  Don't know what is "add all the source files in the dlib/external folder into your project " . Can someone give a screenshot? If I just put paths of the four folders in "additional include directories", I will get link error.

A answer here  may works in  VS2013 [how to load jpeg file using DLIB libarary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32736149/how-to-load-jpeg-file-using-dlib-libarary). In 2015 there is no library branch as shown in the screenshot.

DLIB_PNG_SUPPORT and DLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT have been defined .

I built the examples with default cmakelist, then ran the facedetectionex. It still didn't work when I input a jpeg image.

Comment: did you tried to build library with cmake first and link it as normal .lib file?

Comment: No. I just built with cmake, then open the ALL_BUILD.vcxproj with VS2015. set 3d_point_cloud_ex as start up. debug X64 mode, and ran it. it worked. 3d points cloud showed. But when I ran face_detection_ex with jpeg. It didn't work.

Comment: looks like you have already installed libjpeg in your system and it does not work with dlib. sometimes it comes with python distributions. try building dlib with its own libjpeg implementation. to make this - look at the "cmake .." output - it will show you info about libjpeg. if you will have problems - update your question and show us output from "cmake .."